# Plot over Seaborn plot and add legend

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, seaborn

See the code below. I create a plot with `seaborn` then I plot some other values over the same figure with `plt.plot`, works fine, but the `plt.legend` method apparently is not additive, that is, I cannot use it to label both lines in the chart, which would be `'from seaborn'` and `'from plt'`, both associated with the proper line color.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
mean, cov = [0, 2], [(1, .5), (.5, 1)]
data_sample, y = np.random.multivariate_normal(mean, cov, size=100).T
data_min = min(data_sample)
data_max = max(data_sample)
plot_points = [(data_min + (i/100) * (data_max-data_min)) for i in range(0, 100)]
sns.set(color_codes=True)
plt.figure()
ax = sns.kdeplot(data_sample, legend='from seaborn')
ax.plot(plot_points, y)
plt.legend(['from plt'])
plt.show()
```

How can I address this?

Comment: Try `ax = sns.kdeplot(..., label='from seaborn')`; `ax.plot(..., label='from plot')` and `plt.legend()` without parameters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `legend` to `label` and add `label` to `plot`:

```
ax = sns.kdeplot(data_sample, label='from seaborn')
ax.plot(plot_points, y, label='from plt')
ax.legend()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: As you've posted it doesn't work for me. It happened along with calling `plt.legend()` without parameters, as @JohanC suggested. Did you exclude the `plt.legend` call? If not, consider editing your answer to mention it, then I'll accept it.

Comment: I used  `ax.legend()` instead of `plt.legend()`. See update. But `plt.legend()` also work for me. Both without any parameters.